# Apple's clang++ fails with missing symbol ___cxa_deleted_virtual for virtual delete function definition

Tags: c++, macos, clang++

In order to learn [delete function definition](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2326.html#delete), I'm trying to compile following C++ program that defines a virtual function as `delete` and another class as child class:

```
class V {
  virtual void foo() = delete;
};
class C: V {
  // Any valid definition of foo for Apple's clang++?  
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  C c = C();
  return 0;
}
```

However, this program fails to compile, no matter how I define `foo` in `C`.

```
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -std=c++11 -Wc++11-extensions -v test_virtual.cpp 
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.11.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name test_virtual.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 274.2 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0 -stdlib=libc++ -Wc++11-extensions -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/suztomo/Documents/beringei/beringei -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 140 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.11.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/q6/wnd9wfkj0_50wpwhvfyn0kmh0000gn/T/test_virtual-173a58.o -x c++ test_virtual.cpp
clang -cc1 version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1) default target x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.11.0 -o a.out /var/folders/q6/wnd9wfkj0_50wpwhvfyn0kmh0000gn/T/test_virtual-173a58.o -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___cxa_deleted_virtual", referenced from:
      vtable for C in test_virtual-173a58.o
      vtable for V in test_virtual-173a58.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there valid definition of `foo` in `C` without modifying `V`, that works in Apple's clang++? Or am I missing any command line parameter?

According to [m8r-uyl6ds's post](https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=13684) where this issue doesn't happen in Ubuntu but I don't have other machine than my Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

Comment: Looks like https://reviews.llvm.org/D37830

Comment: @AxelNaumann Thank you. (I no longer write C++ but your reference will help others)